# Is there any "standard" way to utilize the equivalence of Reader and a normal function?

Tags: haskell

I am writing a framework, where the main function asks user about the function of type `a -> [b]`.

However, because that function can be quite complex, its implementation can often look like this:

```
fn a = extractPartOfAAndConvert a ++ extractAnotherPartofAAndConvert a
```

That's why I figured using `Reader` might be a nice, idiomatic idea to fight that. However, at the same time I realize that some people might not want to use a monad.

While experimenting, I've crafted this solution:

```
class Iso a b where
    isoFrom :: a -> b
    isoTo :: b -> a

instance Iso a a where
    isoFrom = id
    isoTo = id

instance Iso (a -> b) (Reader a b) where
    isoFrom f = reader f
    isoTo m = runReader m
```

Which in turn allows me to do:

```
testCallback :: MyState -> Callback -> MyState
testCallback myState cb = cb myState

-- The important signature
testCallbackGeneric :: Iso Callback a => MyState -> a -> MyState
testCallbackGeneric myState cb = (isoTo cb) myState

callbackFunction :: Callback
callbackFunction s = s + 10

callbackMonad :: Reader MyState MyState
callbackMonad = do
    x <- ask
    return $ x - 10

-----------

let myStateA = testCallback myState callbackFunction
-- let myStateB = testCallback myState callbackMonad -- won't work, obviously
let myStateC = testCallbackGeneric myState callbackFunction
let myStateD = testCallbackGeneric myState callbackMonad
```

However, I feel very much like I'm reinventing the wheel.

**Is there a way to express the equivalence of Reader to easily write such generic functions without resorting to creating my own type class?**

Comment: Another thing is whether it's really worthwile to provide such elaborate signature, where the user can simply convert to the preferrable way, just like the instance does. I think there's no reason why that boilerplate shouldn't be avoided/taken off  the user.

Comment: You could use the `MonadReader` constraint, for which there already exists an instance for functions.  If you write `f = do { a <- ask; return $ 2 * a + 3 * a }`, then you can use it as a function as `f 1 == 5` or in any `Reader` function where `f :: MonadReader Int m => m Int`.  This can specialize to `Int -> Int` or `Reader Int Int`.

Comment: @bheklilr *for which there already exists an instance for functions.* THIS. This was what I was missing the whole time! Write this as an answer so I can upvote it! :) (and yes `Callback` is just `MyState -> MyState`, and `MyState ~ Int`)

Comment: Good to know!  Glad it was a simple solution.  Turns out you were definitely reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use the fact that the function monad `(->) r` already has an instance for `MonadReader r` defined in `Control.Monad.Reader`.  You can write functions using just the `MonadReader` constraint and use them either as normal functions or in other `ReaderT` monads:

```
f :: MonadReader Int m => m Int
f = do
    a <- ask
    return $ 2 * a + 3 * a

normally :: Int
normally = f 1
-- normally == 5

readerly :: Reader Int Int
readerly = do
    result <- f
    return $ 2 * result

> runReader f 1
5
> runReader readerly 1
10
```