# What's the difference between Monad.Reader and the (->) monads?

Tags: haskell, monads

I learned that Monad.Reader is actually an encapsulation of a function, namely:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }
```

Which is made an instance of Monad,

```
instance Monad (Reader r) where
    return a = Reader $ \_ -> a
    m >>= k  = Reader $ \r -> runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

In contrast, I knew that (->) is also a Monad,

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    return = const
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

From the definitions it's able to see that they actually behave the same exactly.

So are they interchangeable in all usages? And what's the actual significance of differing these two Monads?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any "standard" way to utilize the equivalence of Reader and a normal function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613651/is-there-any-standard-way-to-utilize-the-equivalence-of-reader-and-a-normal-fu)

Comment: In short, it's about being able to use `do` notation and `>>=`. You can take a parameter into context instead of passing it explicitely: `f >>= g >>= h` vs `f a . g a . h a`. Underlying mechanics are the same.

Comment: You can use do notation with the normal arrow type as well since its instance of `Monad`

Comment: The main difference is that `Monad Reader` is in the title of an important [Haskell magazine](https://themonadreader.wordpress.com/).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks for linking that to related question. But I think the point in my question is not a duplication to that one. For which that question asks for the *way to utilize the equivalence* and I was looking for the *explanations of the significance* :-)

Comment: @dfeuer: So consider to found a journal called `(->)` next time xD

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## TL;DR

They are the same.

## Some history lessons

`State`, `Writer` and `Reader` were inspired by Mark P. Jones' [Functional Programming with Overloading and
Higher-Order Polymorphism](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/springschool95.pdf), where he defined `Reader` as follows:

> A `Reader` monad is used to allow a computation to access the values held
>   in some enclosing environment (represented by the type `r` in the following
>   definitions).
>
> ```
> > instance Monad (r->) where
> >     result x = \r -> x
> >     x `bind` f = \r -> f (x r) r
> ```
>
> As a passing comment, it is interesting to note that these two functions are
>   just the standard `K` and `S` combinators of combinatory logic.

Later, he defines (almost) today's `MonadReader`:

> `Reader monads` : A class of monads for describing computations that consult some fixed environment:
>
> ```
> > class Monad m => ReaderMonad m r where
> >     env :: r -> m a -> m a
> >     getenv :: m r
>
> > instance ReaderMonad (r->) r where
> >     env e c = \_ -> c e
> >     getenv = id
> ```

`getenv` is simply `ask`, and `env` is `local . const`. Therefore, this definition already contained all significant parts of a `Reader`. Ultimately, Jones defines the monad transformer `ReaderT` (`BComp` is backward composition):

> To begin with, it is useful to define two different forms of composition; forwards (`FComp`) and backwards (`BComp`):
>
> ```
> > data FComp m n a = FC (n (m a))
> > data BComp m n a = BC (m (n a))
> ```
>
> [omitting Functor, Monad and OutOf instances]
>
> ```
> > type ReaderT r = BComp (r ->)
> ```

Since `StateT`, `WriterT`, and others had their non-transformer variant, it was only logical to have a `Reader r`, which really is the same as `(->) r`.

Either way, nowadays `Reader`, `Writer` and `State` are defined in terms of their transformer variant, and you use their respective `Monad*` typeclass (`MonadReader`).

## Conclusion

> So are they interchangeable in all usages?

Yes.

> And what's the actual significance of differing these two Monads?

None, **except** that `ReaderT` is actually a monad transformer, which makes things easier.

Comment: Why do my answers lately go into ~20 year old papers or documents, or GCC/GHC's core?

Comment: Could you add the definition of `BComp` for completeness? I imagine it's something like `newtype BComp f g x = BComp (g (f x))`?

Answer (score 1):

They are both instance of the [`MonadReader` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader-Class.html#t:MonadReader). So yes, you can use one instead of the other.

Answer (score 0):

They are in fact the exact same.
We can make this more formal by mapping between them:
`toArrow :: Reader r a -> r -> a` and `toReader :: (r -> a) -> Reader r a`
with implementations `toReader = Reader` and `toArrow = runReader`.

Edit: The semantic behind a `Reader` is that it holds some read-only configuration which you can thread through your chain of computations.
You should always prefer a `Reader` over using the plain arrow type when your want to thread some configuration information, because it is part of a very generic interface that provides useful helper functions, a `MonadReader` class for manipulating `Reader` like data types as well as a `ReaderT` for stacking `Monad`s.